# Finding documents in mongodb collection by order of elements index of array field

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Array field in collection:

```
"fruits": [                    "fruits": [                    "fruits": [
    {"fruit1": "banana"},          {"fruit2": "apple"},           {"fruit3": "pear"},
    {"fruit2": "apple"},           {"fruit4": "orange"},          {"fruit2": "apple"}, 
    {"fruit3": "pear"},            {"fruit1": "banana"},          {"fruit4": "orange"},
    {"fruit4": "orange"}           {"fruit3": "pear"}             {"fruit1": "banana"} 
]
```

I need to find those documents in collections, where "banana" signed before "apple". Does mongodb allows to compare elements in array just like :

```
if (fruits.indexOf('banana') < fruits.indexOf('apple')) return true;
```

Or maybe there is any other method to get result i need?

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB's array query operations do not support any positional search as you want.

You can, however, write a `$where` query to do what you want:

```js
db.yourCollection.find({
  $where: function() { 
    return (this.fruits.indexOf('banana') < this.fruits.indexOf('apple')) 
  }
})
```

Be advised though, you won't be able to use indexes here and the performance will be a problem.

Another approach you can take is to rethink the database design, if you can specify what it is you're trying to build, someone can give you specific advise.

One more approach: pre-calculate the boolean value before persisting to DB as a field and query on true / false.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I also consider another schema which includes some flag to simplify my queries to db. I just tryed all variants to understant where is more effective path.

Answer (score 1):

Consider refactoring your schema if possible. The dynamic field names(i.e. fruit1, fruit2...) make it unnecessarily complicated to construct a query. Also, if you require frequent queries by array index, you should probably store your array entries in individual documents with some sort keys to facilitate sorting with index.

Nevertheless, it is achievable through `$unwind` and `$group` the documents again. With `includeArrayIndex` clause, you can get the index inside array.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": {
      path: "$fruits",
      includeArrayIndex: "idx"
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      fruits: {
        "$objectToArray": "$fruits"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "bananaIdx": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": {
            $eq: [
              "banana",
              {
                $first: "$fruits.v"
              }
            ]
          },
          "then": "$idx",
          "else": "$$REMOVE"
        }
      },
      "appleIdx": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": {
            $eq: [
              "apple",
              {
                $first: "$fruits.v"
              }
            ]
          },
          "then": "$idx",
          "else": "$$REMOVE"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      fruits: {
        $push: {
          "$arrayToObject": "$fruits"
        }
      },
      bananaIdx: {
        $max: "$bananaIdx"
      },
      appleIdx: {
        $max: "$appleIdx"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $lt: [
          "$bananaIdx",
          "$appleIdx"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: [
      "bananaIdx",
      "appleIdx"
    ]
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZrmJ0lE8eAx)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! You are right, it`s better to refactor my schema, because even using your code, its realy increase latency when asking thousands of documents.